# Change the text wrapping of the MDCTextField placeholder text

Tags: ios, material-components

Does anyone know how to change the text wrapping of the placeholder text in the MDCTextField, so that the placeholder label behave like having 0 number of lines.

I don't want '...' anywhere when the placeholder text is long

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently supported. Please follow https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/2268 to track implementation of this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MDCMultilineTextField instead. 
See the material components page about all types of Material TextField:

https://material.io/develop/ios/components/textfields/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is MDCTextField? I'm assuming it is a custom `UITextField`

`UITextField` is specifically one-line only. Use a `UITextView` instead.

Comment: MDCTextField is a component in Material design library developed by google for iOS. It contains a placeholder label ,textfield, underline view, error label and word count label.What I want to know is there a way to make the placeholder label multi-line.

Comment: No. You can't. Textfield is one-line only.